# Resizing and re-ordering in ag-grid is not working on IPAD in angular 2

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Is there any support for ag-grid in Ipad ?
Grid is loading perfectly and all the events are working fine.Only resizing and re-ordering is not working in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-touch/#gsc.tab=0

Re-ordering should be possible with touch and drag. Resizing does not seem to be possible with touch. Did you try double-tap on header borders (aka size-to-fit)?